# Does a time varying gain (AGC) mitigate clutter in radar signals?

Tags: radar

Trying to implement an MTI filter for flatland clutter in a radar received pulses.

However, after the matched filter output instead of implementing directly the MTI filter, I normalized with an automatic gain model.

The simulation is from matlab examples on radar sys design, what im i doing wrong?

MF output

[image: MF Output]

AGC output
[image: AGC Output]

Comment: sorry i edited the links

Comment: included the images directly in your question.

Comment: And what exactly you think is wrong with the result--- it appears the AGC is doing what you would expect. Also what is the time constant for the AGC and what were you intending to have happen?

Comment: my question is, if agc is sufficient to mitigate clutter, why do we need and MTI filter and its associated problems (blindspeed, incoherent phase in transmitter...)

Comment: @carterwild Can you explain what your scenario is? For example, are you attempting to detect some number of targets in clutter? Or is this clutter only?

Comment: @Envidia yes i'm attempting to detect targets in presence of clutter, as you see in the first image there is a large peak in the beginning, thats clutter but after AGC (second picture) it just disappear! why would i use an MTI filter then ?!

Comment: @carterwild You seem to be concentrating on the absolute value of the signal levels. In general when you play with gain only, you will not improve signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) or clutter-to-signal (CSR) ratio. In other words, AGC changes the signal levels of both clutter and the target of interest, and you will not be able to detect the target any easier than before AGC.